# ios segue on condition

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to perform segue after some condition. I created modal segue in main Storyboard from nextPushed button to next view controller.

```
(IBAction)nextPushed:(id)sender {
//Perform check that every field /date/from/to/ choised and exists  
NSString *fromText = [NSString alloc];
NSString *toText = [NSString alloc];
NSString *pasNumText = [NSString alloc];
NSString *dateText = [NSString alloc];
dateText = self.dateAndTimeLabel.text;
fromText = self.fromLabel.text;
toText = self.toLabel.text;
pasNumText = self.numOfPassengersLabel.text;
if (!([fromText isEqual:@"Choice" ]) && !([toText isEqual:@"Choice"] ) && !([pasNumText isEqual:@"Choice"]) && !([dateText isEqual:@"Choice"])) {
    NSLog(@"All fields choisen");
    NSLog(@"Going to next view");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToDannie" sender:sender];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Not all fields selected" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

It is performing segue even if condition is not true and showing alert in next view.

Comment: I have edited your code for clarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Delete the segue from the button to the view controller.  Instead, control-drag from the view controller that contains the nextButton to the view controller you want to segue to.  Then the performSegueWithIdentifier will run only if it meets the conditions.

Comment: Thanks it was fast and helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

When you want a conditional segue, you should make the segue from the controller (rather than the button). Then if you condition is met, use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: to trigger the segue.

Comment: Appreciate you help !